# Makefile target to check for clean git diff

Tags: bash, git, makefile

I am trying to write a `Makefile` target that checks for no uncomitted changes in the git repository where it is ran after running another target.

This is what I have so far:

```
check-git-clean: other-target
ifneq ($(shell git diff-index --quiet HEAD; echo $$?), 0)
    $(error "There are uncomitted changes after running make other-target")
endif
```

However, what I am experiencing is that if the `other-target` causes uncommitted changes, the `ifneq` will not catch it. On the other hand, if there were already uncommitted changes *before* I run `make check-git-clean`, then the `ifneq` does catch it.

So, in a way, it's almost as if the `ifneq` is running "before" the `make other-target` but the CLI output (echo) I get are in the right order.

I'm wondering how I can do this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In libexec/git-core there's a `git-sh-setup` set of common utility routines for git commands and hooks, including `require_clean_worktree`. The meat of that is

```
git update-index -q --ignore-submodules --refresh
git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules
git diff-index --cached --quiet --ignore-submodules HEAD --
```

where the index refresh is a safety play to deal with the chance you've just finished restoring your worktree from a backup or something, diff-files compares indexed content against worktree content and diff-index compares arbitrary repo content against indexed (in this case, because of `--cached`) content.  The return codes on those last two commands are what you're after.

Answer (score 6):

May I recommend to use [`git diff --exit-code`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---exit-code) directly?

```
.PHONY: check-git-clean
check-git-clean: other-target
    git diff --quiet
```

or

```
.PHONY: check-git-clean
check-git-clean: other-target
    git diff-index --quiet HEAD
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the condition to be executed when the rule is executed rather than when the makefile is parsed, you need to use the `if` function.

```
# This function tests whether both arguments are equals
equals = $(and $(findstring $1,$2),$(findstring $2,$1))

check-git-clean: other-target
    $(if $(call equals,0,$(shell git diff-index --quiet HEAD; echo $$?)),, \
        $(error There are uncomitted changes after running make $?) \
    )
```

However, you may prefer to use a more natural approach to error out:

```
check-git-clean: other-target
    git diff-index --quiet HEAD
```

Comment: Oof. Why all the (non-portable) functions? Just run the git diff directly

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You're right the question doesn't say it's GNU make, and errorring does not need to be done with the `error` function. I'm adding a second simple shell-based solution.

Comment: That's still pretzel logic. Each shell command returns an exit code and `make` examines that exit code. It can be clean and simple.

Comment: @tripleee I agree technically, and that's what we're relying on with the `false` call and the `||` operator, but the exact `git` command he's running is silent and will not inform the user about what is wrong. This convoluted error handling is helping the user preserve his mental heath.

Comment: Actually, make would complain that rule `check-git-clean` failed, which should be sufficient to know what's wrong.

Comment: Everyone complains when the computer talks, so let it just beeps (evolved error message removed).